# How to find multiple values in an xml using sfk tool (swiss file knife)

Tags: batch-file

I am working on this script to find two tags (values) within an xml but i believe i am missing out on something as it doesn't seem to be working fine.

script:

sfk find "PATH%\Env\Test\En.xml" "60000" "1234"

Please note that in the xml these two tags 
1. "60000"
2. "1234"  are at different locations.

How can i find these two values in the same line of script i.e finding multiple values.?

i have tested it with just one value and it works fine but i try to look for both values together it just doesn't work.

Comment: Is it in a `specific order` or can the `two numbers be in either order`?  Are the numbers `surrounded by spaces`?  If not, will you ever get a number like `612346` which has `1234` embedded in it?

Comment: Thanks for your response foxidrive, but my requirement has changed since i submitted this question. Now i am looking for 8 different <version></version> numbers in En.xml and as per what matches i ask my script to run the respective code in my batch script.

Comment: for ex: sfk find :%PATH%\Env\Test\En.xml" "<version>802</version>" "<version>902</version>" "<version>1102</version>" "<version>1202</version>" 
If "<version>802</version>" GOTO RUN_v802 ELSE EXIT
Something like this. How can i do this using sfk in batch script.

Comment: Do you need to find all 8 terms in the file, and then branch to do something?

Comment: Yes, look for all items and whichever matches -> do the respective job. So after looking for all versions if <version>902</version matches then GOTO RUNPATCH_v902.  But i am not sure how to lookup for all these values in a single command and then how to handle the return value

Comment: MY requirement:

sfk find  "%PATH%\Env\Test\En.xml" "<Version>8200</Version>" "<Version>8610</Version>" "<Version>8720</Version>" "<Version>8900</Version>" "<Version>8930</Version>"
"<Version>9010</Version>" "<Version>1100</Version>" "<Version>1200</Version>" 
----------
IF EQUALS "<Version>9010</Version>" GOTO RUNPATCH_v9

Comment: So basically, i am looking for all those values in that xml to see which version of software is installed on the machine and based on the return value i want my script to run the relvant version patch.

Comment: The task needs further clarification.  You obviously don't want to perform one single task when `every search term` is present, but you want to perform different tasks depending on which search term is present.  The rules for the task need to be spelled out - IE do you want to search for them in numerical order, and only process the first one?  There can be many ways to process a bunch of search terms and it needs to be clear to write a working script.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your comment above, this is one way that will allow you to process different tasks for each version number:

Don't use `%PATH%` as your variable name because it will break lots of things.

```
@echo off
find "<version>802</version>"  < "%PATH%\Env\Test\En.xml"  >nul && goto :found_802
find "<version>902</version>"  < "%PATH%\Env\Test\En.xml"  >nul && goto :found_902
find "<version>1102</version>" < "%PATH%\Env\Test\En.xml"  >nul && goto :found_1102
find "<version>1202</version>" < "%PATH%\Env\Test\En.xml"  >nul && goto :found_1202
echo Version not found
pause
goto :eof

:found_802 
echo do stuff for 802
goto :eof
:found_902 
echo do stuff for 902
goto :eof
:found_1102
echo do stuff for 1102
goto :eof
:found_1202
echo do stuff for 1202
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks, i am not using %PATH& as a variable, just mentioned it in example. I tried running my script in this manner but it cannot find the value in the xml. Although it is present within the xml. so as per above it should say found_802 and then echo do stuff for 802 but instead it just runs all the command and finds nothings....

Comment: Is the syntax in the above script correct here: 

 < "%PATH%\Env\Test\En.xml"  >nul && goto : found_802

The two tags <> are they correctly spaced out?

Comment: It should be right. What do you see on the console?  The terms that are being searched for are case sensitive, if you didn't provide the actual terms.  Spacing is fine.

Comment: it works when i use sfk find command and then check Errorlevel but doesn't work with a simple find